# MVC6 select tag helper for edit applying current value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a viewmodel with a state dropdownlist.

The form is being populated from a database and I everything works except I dont know how to apply the current value for state as the default value for the select helper tag?

This is the CSHTML for the select:

```
  <select asp-for="State" asp-items="@Model.StatesList" > </select>
```

This provides the all the states when you do a dropdown however is there a way to set the value to the current value for Model eg @Model.state so if you dont select any new dropdown value it takes the original value for the record?

Comment: Just set the value of `State` in the controller before you pass the model to the view (if it matches the value of one of your options with will be selected)

Comment: Just checked and indeed the value for state is one of the dropdown items. Its set to "Victoria" in the view model and this is also one of the items in the dropdown.

Comment: Is the `value` attribute "Victoria", (i.e. `<option value="Victoria">`) or is that the display text?

Comment: The value attribute should have been "VIC" and it was instead set to the display text "Victoria".. thats why it wasnt working. I modified the value to be "VIC" and it worked perfectly.